# Optional Qt string translation

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I have something like this:

```
void FooWidget:showSomeDialog(bool is_translatable)
{
  QMessageBox mbox(this);
  if (is_translatable)
  {
    mbox.setWindowsTitle(tr("Title"));
    mbox.setText(tr("Text"));
    mbox.setInformativeText(tr("InformativeText"));
    mbox.addButton(tr("Button1"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
    mbox.addButton(tr("Button2"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
    ...
  } else {
    mbox.setWindowsTitle(QLatin1String("Title"));
    mbox.setText(QLatin1String("Text"));
    mbox.setInformativeText(QLatin1String("InformativeText"));
    mbox.addButton(QLatin1String("Button1"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
    mbox.addButton(QLatin1String("Button2"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
    ...
  }
  mbox.exec();
}
```

What is a better way to avoid duplication?

I've tried to use lambda function like this:

```
  auto func = is_translatable
              ? [](const char *str) -> QString { return tr(str); }
              : [](const char *str) -> QString { return QLatin1String(str); };
```

But it doesn't work. Moreover it doesn't look quite good.

Comment: How about a function that takes the is_translatable parameter and returns the string? That way you get rid of code duplication, the if condition (you use it only inside the "translation function" and the same function could be used for other cases.

Comment: I think you're misusing the translation system. In a translated application, UI strings should always go via `tr()`. Select the desired language to have them appear "untranslated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the preprocessor

```
#define TRANSLATE(cond, str) (cond) ? tr(str) : QLatin1String(str)
```

and then use that so you don't need the outer `if`anymore.

```
mbox.setWindowsTitle(TRANSLATE(is_translatable, "Title"))
```

Comment: Yes, it's the simplest way come to mind, but I'm wondering if C++1x provides a better way using lambda functions. Just don't really like using preprocessor.

Comment: What are the advantages of using macro over plain function in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda this way:

```
void FooWidget:showSomeDialog(bool is_translatable)
{
    auto makeLatin = [](auto const& str) {return QLatin1String(str);};
    auto lambda = [this](auto& fun) {
        this->mbox.setWindowsTitle(fun("Title"));
        this->mbox.setText(fun("Text"));
        this->mbox.setInformativeText(fun("InformativeText"));
        this->mbox.addButton(fun("Button1"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
        this->mbox.addButton(fun("Button2"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
        ...
    };
    if (is_translatable)
    {
        lambda(tr);
    } else {
        lambda(makeLatin);
    }
    mbox.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a translate method:

```
void FooWidget::translate(bool is_translatable, QString value)
{
   if(is_translatable) return tr(value)
   return QLatin1String(value);
}

void FooWidget:showSomeDialog(bool is_translatable)
{
  QMessageBox mbox(this);
  mbox.setWindowsTitle(translate(is_translatable, "Title");
  mbox.setText(translate(is_translatable, "Text"));
  mbox.setInformativeText(translate(is_translatable, "InformativeText"));
  mbox.addButton(translate(is_translatable, "Button1"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
  mbox.addButton(translate(is_translatable, "Button2"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
  mbox.exec();
}
```

If is_translatable could be a member of FooWidget it would be a little neater to read too:

```
void FooWidget::translate(QString value)
{
   if(this->is_translatable) return tr(value)
   return QLatin1String(value);
}

void FooWidget:showSomeDialog()
{
  QMessageBox mbox(this);
  mbox.setWindowsTitle(translate("Title");
  mbox.setText(translate("Text"));
  mbox.setInformativeText(translate("InformativeText"));
  mbox.addButton(translate("Button1"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
  mbox.addButton(translate("Button2"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
  mbox.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I was looking for:

```
void FooWidget:showSomeDialog(std::function<QString(const char*)> tr)
{
  QMessageBox mbox(this);
  mbox.setWindowsTitle(tr("Title"));
  mbox.setText(tr("Text"));
  mbox.setInformativeText(tr("InformativeText"));
  mbox.addButton(tr("Button1"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
  mbox.addButton(tr("Button2"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
  ...
  mbox.exec();
}
```

Usage:

```
showSomeDialog([](const char* s){ return QString::fromLatin1(s); });
showSomeDialog([](const char* s){ return FooWidget::tr(s); });
```